# Trying to delete a row from Cosmos DB in C# code

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to delete of a row from a Cosmos db container. I have only ID. The PartitionKey is different ie, Category column. But I don't have category value while deleting. I am new to Cosmos DB. Is there any approach to perform this?

```
 var task = await this.MainContainer.DeleteItemAsync<T>(id, new PartitionKey("Category1"));
```

Comment: why don't you retrieve the item before you delete it?

Comment: its multiple transaction. Is there any other way. Its a drawback I guess. How come if we always knows partition key.

Comment: It is common practice to retrieve all partitions and keep it in memory, & then run multiple delete command in parallel (or in bulk) against all partitions. Also please clarify if it is ok to delete from all partitions or just in particular.

Comment: I want to delete from all partitions.Keep in memory means?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know the value of partition key and the document does have a partition field , use `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` property to enable cross partition queries.

Then, query your document by `Id` and fetch it's `SelfLink` property. Use this `SelfLink` value to Delete your document.

**Code:**

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions
        {
            MaxItemCount = 10,
            EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
        };
        var id = '1';
        var queryString = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id= '" + id + "'";
        var queryInSql = documentDbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(
                               "uri",
                               queryString,
                               queryOptions).AsDocumentQuery();
        var document = await queryInSql.ExecuteNextAsync<Document>().ConfigureAwait(false);

        //Delete a document using its selfLink property
        //To get the documentLink you would have to query for the Document, using CreateDocumentQuery(),  and then refer to its .SelfLink property
        await documentDbClient.DeleteDocumentAsync(document.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault().SelfLink);
```

Comment: This will only work if the id of the document is unique in the collection. I'm not sure whether OP can confirm if this is the case in this instance.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Krishnan. There was no mention of uniqueness of `Id`, so considering it's default state and no changes there, I have provided this answer. But, if `id` is not unique, in that case the solution will slightly change.

Comment: but I can not write the inline query like this. My code is generic

Comment: The configuration and method will remain the same, you will have to convert it to generic. If you can provide your code for querying and delete, I can convert it for you.